Dark mode using cookie in static pages in Nextjs?
I'm aware that you can accomplish what I'm looking for using localStorage or next-themes. However, for my current setup I need to save the user's dark mode preference as a cookie instead of localStorage, as I want the dark mode setting to persist across several subdomains.
My issue is that when I try to check the cookies in the server pages, they turn into SSR instead of SSG when rendered.
Is it possible to have statically generated pages that work for both light and dark mode in Nextjs 15 (without getting any flash during the initial render)? For example using the middleware or a provider?
